# Whats wrong with the following code?

Tags: c, eclipse

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { max_size_string = 127 };
static char string[max_size_string + 1] = " ";

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    printf("Type a string");
    fgets(string, max_size_string, stdin);
    printf("The string is %s",string);
    return 0;
}
```

In console screen, Type a string is appearing after typing something, and after that, other printf is printing the output. I am unable to understand the order of execution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `printf()` buffers output until either

- it gets a line ending (`\n`)
- you `fflush(stdout)`
- you close the stream (including it closing automatically when the program exits)

See if the following makes more sense

```
printf("Type a string ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(string, max_size_string, stdin);
printf("The string is %s\n",string); // << Note I've added a line ending
return 0;
```